# Detecting common SQL injection patterns in a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, sql-injection

I'm using the ezSQL PHP class for MySQL queries. Since all of my queries pass through the `$ezsql->query()` function, I thought it would be a good idea to implement a method to block common SQL injection techniques from `$ezsql->query()`.

For example, the most common one is probably `1=1`. So this regular expression should be able to block all variations of that:

```
preg_match('/(?:"|\')?(\d)(?:"|\')?=(?:"|\')?\1(?:"|\')?/',$query);
```

This would block `"1"="1"`, `'1'=1`, `1=1`, etc.

Is this a good idea? If so, what are some other common patterns?

Edit: Forgot to mention, I do use validation and sanitation. This is just an extra precaution.

Comment: A better idea would be to use something that allows you to do prepared statements + parameter binding, which would avoid most common attacks altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a good idea?

No. For two reasons:

1. You're doing it wrong (yes you just failed with your bare approach of a SQL blacklist). And no, I won't tell you how you could improve that because of 2:
2. It's a blacklist approach. You should not use a blacklist approach inside the database class itself. That's no added pre-caution, it's just useless. Blacklist could be added additionally at the request level of the webserver for example.

Instead use an existing blacklist, don't re-invent the wheel. If you want to learn how to develop your own SQL blacklist layer, help with the development of such existing components. This sort of security is not out-of-the-box so that you can just throw in a question like yours and you can actually expect concrete answers. Take care.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a good idea?

Definitely NO.

**Every time** I see such a suggestion on an internet forum, I am wondering, what if the software this forum runs on followed such a pattern? A poor inventor would be just unable co come up with their solution, because software would block the post!

> extra precautions wouldn't hurt. Better safe than sorry.

As I pointed out above, it apparently hurts. A database that cannot process some odd portions of data is a nonsense.

Besides, I do believe that only **knowledge** can make you safe.
Not random moves out of some vague ideas but sane and reasonable actions.

As long as you escape **and quote** the data that goes to the query and as long as you set the proper encoding for the escaping function, there is no reason to sorrow.
As long as you are using prepared statements to add your data to the query, there is no reason to sorrow.
As long as you are filtering SQL identifiers and keywords based on hardcoded whitelist, there is no reason to sorrow.